# How to remove a layer from a nested JSON object / dictionary based on key value pair?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a large nested JSON file that I need to remove a layer from, something similar to the following:

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "FirstLayer 1",
      "type": "Folder",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "ID12345",
          "type": "Folder",
          "children": [
            {
              "key1": "abc",
              "key3": "Float8"
            },
            {
              "key2": "abc",
              "key4": "Float8"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "FirstLayer",
      "type": "Folder",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "ID98765",
          "type": "Folder",
          "children": [
            {
              "key1": "abc",
              "key3": "Float8"
            },
            {
              "key2": "abc",
              "key4": "Float8"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There are a bunch of separate layers I need to remove-- they're all at the same indentation level, if that makes a difference.

In this example, I need to remove the layer(s) with the "name": "ID12345" and "name "ID98765" and everything at that level / layer.

The desired outcome would be like the following, with that layer removed:

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "FirstLayer 1",
      "type": "Folder",
      "children": [
          {
            "key1": "abc",
            "key3": "Float8"
          },
          {
            "key2": "abc",
            "key4": "Float8"
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "FirstLayer",
      "type": "Folder",
      "children": [
          {
            "key1": "abc",
            "key3": "Float8"
          },
          {
            "key2": "abc",
            "key4": "Float8"
          }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can't use dict.pop since as far as I know, it pops out the key value pair based on the key name, not the value. In addition, it wouldn't pop out the related "type" and "children" key-value pairs underneath that go with it.
Are there any other functions that would use the key-value instead? Or would this have to be an entirely custom function / looping job here?

Would like to accomplish this with Python but am open to other ways as well.

Comment: did you try something like: `for d in data['children']: d['children'] = d['children'][0]['children']`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. Once you've loaded it, it's just lists and dictionaries, it makes no difference where they came from.

Comment: @cottontail Yes, so actually in the example, the children may have many more children-- there's an unknown number of levels deep that it may go past that level, and we'd want to retain all of them in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep track of grandparents, parents and children you can promote children to parents via a comprehension. Note that this mutates your original data which is something you may or may not want to do.

**Given:**

```py
data = {
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "FirstLayer 1",
      "type": "Folder",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "ID12345",
          "type": "Folder",
          "children": [
            {
              "key1": "abc",
              "key3": "Float8"
            },
            {
              "key2": "abc",
              "key4": "Float8"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "FirstLayer",
      "type": "Folder",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "ID98765",
          "type": "Folder",
          "children": [
            {
              "key1": "abc",
              "key3": "Float8"
            },
            {
              "key2": "abc",
              "key4": "Float8"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Then this:**

```py
for grand_parent in data["children"]:
    grand_parent["children"] = [
        child
        for parent in grand_parent["children"]
        for child in parent["children"]
    ]

import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

**Should give you:**

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "FirstLayer 1",
            "type": "Folder",
            "children": [
                {
                    "key1": "abc",
                    "key3": "Float8"
                },
                {
                    "key2": "abc",
                    "key4": "Float8"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "FirstLayer",
            "type": "Folder",
            "children": [
                {
                    "key1": "abc",
                    "key3": "Float8"
                },
                {
                    "key2": "abc",
                    "key4": "Float8"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```